# Scrapy - Login process on two webpage

Tags: python, parsing, authentication, scrapy

I've write a Scrapy crawler for parse data from https://www.mysonicwall.com/.

They change their login page, before username and password were in the same form on the same page and i was able to login well with this code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'ctl00$_mainContent$USERNAME': 'dummymail', 'ctl00$_mainContent$Password': 'dummypassword'},  #
        cookies={'cookie': 'dummydatacookie',},  # 
        callback=self.after_login
    )
```

Now login and password are on two separated form on two webpage (first page for username and second for password).

How can I do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Happy to help, but your question doesn't show that you've attempted to seek a solution to your problem yourself. What have you tried? In your particular case, why not try posting the first form, followed by the second form? If you hit problems at that stage, would be a right time to ask a question here.

Comment: If you pay me $20/hour I can do that, apart from being sarcastic, StackOverflow is not for questions like this, first you have to write some and if you incur any problem, ask here, but never ask questions like "Can you develop it for me"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) and [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to automate the login process. 
It does require a fair bit of setup and use of Lua language.

Otherwise I would try two FormRequests in succession - one for the username and other for the password.